# Android scrolling an image larger than 4096x4096

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an Android application that listens to your microphone input. While it's listening, I have an image containing some sine wave drawings scroll by, to let the user know the application is listening. I have the sine wave image in a horizontal scroll view, which automatically scrolls by. The sine wave image is 8000x484. When I run the application, I get this warning at runtime:

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (8000x484, max=4096x4096)
```

And the sine wave image is not rendered. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hm, I would have created a custom view for it and show only visible part of the image instead full-size image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to split the image into bands, (say, 8 bands, 1000 pixels wide each,) and at any given time keep visible only as many bands as necessary to cover the screen.  (On a screen which is not wider than 1000 pixels, it will be at most 2 bands.)

But if you want my advice, don't do even that, because it would still be computationally expensive, it would consume a lot of memory, it would cause unnecessary battery drain, and it would constitute an attempt to provide a user experience which is considerably more "lush" than what people expect from a timid voice recording application.